# Is the XML parsing slow, or is the SQL insertion methodology the bottleneck?

Tags: xml, csv, xml-parsing, sql-server-ce, database-performance

Although I think it's likely that it's the volume of data that's causing the problem, and not the way we're sending/parsing it (and the fact that the device receiving the data is a 98-lb. weakling (old handheld device running Windows CE using .NET 1.1)), I have been tasked with changing the XML processing of some data to parsing the CSV files that will come down in their stead.

The "problematic" data is the typical XML fare:

```
<PlatypusItems>
    <PlatypusID>DARINTULIP</PlatypusID>
    <PlatypusItemID>010476</PlatypusItemID>
    <ItemID>01820000468</ItemID>
    <BillSize>15</BillSize>
  </PlatypusItems>
  <PlatypusItems>
    <PlatypusID>DARINTULIP</PlatypusID>
    <PlatypusItemID>011065</PlatypusItemID>
    <ItemID>01820000478</ItemID>
    <BillSize>15</BillSize>
  </PlatypusItems>
  <PlatypusItems>
    <PlatypusID>DARINTULIP</PlatypusID>
    <PlatypusItemID>015165</PlatypusItemID>
    <ItemID>01820000481</ItemID>
    <BillSize>15</BillSize>
  </PlatypusItems>
  <PlatypusItems>
    <PlatypusID>DARINTULIP</PlatypusID>
    <PlatypusItemID>010420</PlatypusItemID>
    <ItemID>01820000907</ItemID>
    <BillSize>24</BillSize>
  </PlatypusItems>
(etc.)
```

In looking into the (legacy - I didn't write it) code that does this, I see a couple of things that look odd (to me, at least), and wonder if they might, rather than data size or parsing methodology, be [at least part of] the problem.

e.g., is there any reason why the var dSQL is used in the second instance below? It is the same thing as the SqlCeCommand's CommandText property, but without using params. To put it in context, I'll show a fair bit of code:

```
if (File.Exists(filePathName)) // <-- filePathName contains the name of the XML file to be parsed
{
    DataSet dset = new DataSet("DuckbillSetup");
    dset.ReadXml(filePathName);

    dSQL = "DELETE FROM Platypi";
    try
    {
        dbconn.DBCommand(dSQL, true);
    }
    catch
    {
        //bla [elided/excised]
    }

    SqlCeConnection conn = dbconn.GetConnection();
    if (conn != null && conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
    {
        conn.Open();
    }
    SqlCeCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();

    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Platypi ( PlatypusID, PlatypusItemID, ItemID, BillSize) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";

    foreach (DataTable tab in dset.Tables)
    {
        if (tab.TableName.ToLower() == "Platypi".ToLower())
        {
            foreach (DataRow row in tab.Rows)
            {
                PlatypusItem PlatypusItm = new PlatypusItem();
                if (!ret)
                    ret = true;
                foreach (DataColumn column in tab.Columns)
                {
                    if (column.ColumnName == "PlatypusID")
                    {
                        PlatypusItm.PlatypusID = (string) row[column];
                    }
                    else if (column.ColumnName == "PlatypusItemID")
                    {
                        if (!row.IsNull(column))
                            PlatypusItm.PlatypusItemID = (string) row[column];
                        else
                            PlatypusItm.PlatypusItemID = "";
                    }
                    else if (column.ColumnName == "ItemID")
                    {
                        if (!row.IsNull(column))
                            PlatypusItm.ItemID = (string) row[column];
                        else
                            PlatypusItm.ItemID = "";
                    }
                    else if (column.ColumnName == "BillSize")
                    {
                        if (!row.IsNull(column))
                            PlatypusItm.BillSize = Convert.ToInt32((string) row[column]);
                        else
                            PlatypusItm.BillSize = 0;
                    }
                }
                PlatypusItemList.List.Add(PlatypusItm);

                dSQL = "INSERT INTO Platypi (PlatypusID, PlatypusItemID, ItemID, BillSize) VALUES (" + PlatypusItm.PlatypusID + ",'" +
                       PlatypusItm.PlatypusItemID + "','" + PlatypusItm.ItemID + "'," + PlatypusItm.BillSize + ")";

                if (!First)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters[0].Value = PlatypusItm.PlatypusID;
                    cmd.Parameters[1].Value = PlatypusItm.PlatypusItemID;
                    cmd.Parameters[2].Value = PlatypusItm.ItemID;
                    cmd.Parameters[3].Value = PlatypusItm.BillSize.ToString();
                }

                if (First)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@PlatypusID", PlatypusItm.PlatypusID);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@PlatypusItemID", PlatypusItm.PlatypusItemID);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ItemID", PlatypusItm.ItemID);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@BillSize", PlatypusItm.BillSize);
                    cmd.Prepare();
                    First = false;
                }

                if (frmCentral.CancelFetchInvDataInProgress)
                {
                    return false;
                }

                try
                {
                    dbconn.DBCommand(cmd, dSQL, true); // <-- Why dSQL? Why not: dbconn.DBCommand(cmd, cmd.CommandText, true);
                }
            . . .
```

...I tend to think the problem is more likely the use of the dSQL in the command (so it's not the parsing of the XML that's the problem, but the insertion into the database, which may be "hicc[ough,up]ing" each time it confronts those class members in the SQL statement that it has to unravel, as opposed to having params to fly through). If it *is* the case that XML parsing is that much less performant than CSV parsing, is there a way to speed it up, or is switching to a CSV file really sensible?

### UPDATE

I just tested by putting MessageBox.Show()s in the code (I have to do it that way - long story already bemoaned in these regions plenty of times), just before and after the parsing/reading of the XML file, and just before and after the for loop that inserts the data. Admittedly, my test data is not voluminous, but in both cases the time between the "begun" and "finished" messages was practically instantaneous...Curious that one would slow down to a crawl (the tester said it took 10 minutes for one site to load, and he extrapolated that it would take 30 minutes for another one (didn't wait for it)).

### UPDATE 2

I don't know quite how to apply the code below excerpted from here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/537kf788(v=vs.90).aspx (linked to in ErikEJ's answer):

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM myTable";
SqlCeResultSet rs = cmd.ExecuteResultSet(ResultSetOptions.Updatable |
    ResultSetOptions.Scrollable);

SqlCeUpdatableRecord rec = rs.CreateRecord();

// Insert 10 records
//
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    rec.SetInt32(0, i);
    rs.Insert(rec);
}
```

Is it really necessary/sensible to read all of the records from the table first? What if it has a gazillion records in it? Or is it not actually doing that?

And what does SetInt32() do? It looks like it might be assuming the table has an ID column that is updating, but that can't be, because usually those would be autoinc'd, so...???

Perhaps *rec.SetInt32(0,i)* is just a placeholder for:

```
rec.MyFirstClassmember(bla);
rec.MySecondClassmember(Blee);
...etc.
```

but at any rate, neither "SqlCeResultSet" nor "SqlCeUpdatableRecord" seems available to me - in fact, with this code:

```
SqlCeResultSet rs = cmd.ExecuteResultSet(ResultSetOptions.Updatable | ResultSetOptions.Scrollable);
SqlCeUpdatableRecord rec = rs.CreateRecord();
```

...everything is red in the VS2003 code editor except "res = cmd.", ".Updatable |", ".Scrollable", and "rec = rs."

There is no "Resolve" context menu item available; I do have "using System.Data.SqlServerCe;" in this unit.

In a nutshell, the problem with this app is it weaves around and under itself like an old-school psychedelic screen saver; the word "spaghetti" has definitely come to mind, and fits, but perhaps a better term would be "eggshells" (think Humpty Dumpty). Which could be a great conundrum: "When does spaghetti turn into eggshells?" Answer: "When badly written code breaks."

### UPDATE 3

In the code in the project in the link provided (http://mobilesandbox.blogspot.dk/2009/02/sql-compact-insert-performance.html) in a comment below:

```
rs = cmd.ExecuteResultSet(ResultSetOptions.Updatable);
rec = rs.CreateRecord();

for(i = 0; i < m_nSampleSize; ++i) 
{
    rec.SetInt32(0, i);
    rs.Insert(rec);
}
```

...it seems as if the same record (rec) is being inserted over and over again. Am I wrong? Is the rs smart enough to know to increment to the next record in the result set each time? If so, why can it not just be a "while not endOfResultSet" loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be the INSERT statements that is causing the slow response for sure. There are methods for avoiding T-SQL and doing INSERTs directly to the "raw" tabel with SQL Server Compact, look for SqlCeUpdateableRecord and SqlCeResultSet.Insert method on MSDN. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/537kf788(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: OK, if you are stuck with .NET CF 1.1 and SQL CE 2.0, you are out of luck, only INSERTs will do the trick.

Comment: Okay, are there any performance tips? It seems we are going to move from an XML file to a CSV file, although I'm not convinced that's going to make much difference.

Comment: Perf tips http://mobilesandbox.blogspot.dk/2009/02/sql-compact-insert-performance.html

Comment: In the code at that link, it seems like the same record is inserted over and over again (updating my question with the code).

Comment: That is not the case, m_nSampleSize records are inserted. And it is not a read loop, it is a INSERT loop.